# TexpadTeX and "LaTeX error: Cannot determine size of graphic in PDF (no bounding box)"

Tags: graphics, pdf, texpad

The following MWE doesn't compile under Texpad 1.8.14 on the Mac, using TexpadTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{pic.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in pic.pdf (no BoundingBox).
```

If an external typesetter is used instead, the document compiles correctly. Also, I have other documents that do work with included PDF graphics under TexpadTeX, so it's not an issue with e.g. TexpadTeX using straight `latex` rather than `pdflatex`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in TexpadTeX due to the inclusion of the `qtree` package after `graphicx`. Swapping the order of the packages fixes it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{pic.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Texpad 1.9.8